# codenameone display entire json response message not just a single node

Tags: java, json, netbeans, codenameone

I am calling a parcel tracking json service using codenameone java code. 
Here is the full json response:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "results": {
    "tracking_reference": "DY954563460NZ",
    "message_id": "682c9b69-7f90-48c6-a36d-3b371e203a96",
    "message_datetime": "2016-11-11T08:08:05.0000000Z",
    "service": "",
    "carrier": ""
  }
}
```

I would like to create a popup that displays the entire response - but all the examples I can see only show how to get the results node.
Here is what I am currently showing:

```
  "results": {
    "tracking_reference": "DY954563460NZ",
    "message_id": "682c9b69-7f90-48c6-a36d-3b371e203a96",
    "message_datetime": "2016-11-11T08:08:05.0000000Z",
    "service": "",
    "carrier": ""
  }
```

This is because I am using this code to get this specific branch:

```
Object responseMessage = null;
responseMessage = apiResponse.get("results");
Dialog d = new Dialog("Response");
d.setScrollable(true);
d.show("Response Message", responseMessage.toString(), "OK", null);
```

According to this website there is a special node called 'root' which should do the trick but it errors out.

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html

Any idea how I can display the entire response message?
Thanks

Comment: @Shai Aimog - thank you that worked. Just FYI for anyone else interested - because I removed the code that populates the variable I had to change this

d.show("Response Message", responseMessage.toString(), "OK", null);

with this line

Dialog.show("Response Message", apiResponse.toString(), "OK", null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
responseMessage = apiResponse.get("results");
```